# Why there is no blood in a bird's egg?

Tags: ornithology

Egg consists of some albumin and yellow colored yolk.

But it is a living organism with red colored blood, it should contain red blood.
so why can't we find the blood in the egg (specifically bird's egg)?

Comment: Simple: You don't see it, because there is no blood in eggs.

Comment: @user60306 seriously, at least show some research effort and instead of calling the egg white 'transparent gel', use its proper term (albumen).

Comment: It is not a living organism. It is a live cell. There is a vast difference.

Answer (score 7):

You do not see blood because you are looking at unfertilized eggs.  These are the chicken eggs that one gets from the supermarket.  The hens are bred to lay these even with no rooster.  No chick will ever grow from these eggs.

If you have a fertilized egg that is about to hatch and open it, you will find a chick.  Inside the chick there is blood, should you wish to check.

If you have a fertilized egg that will hatch eventually and open it, you will find signs of the developing chick.

[image: developing chick in egg]

If the egg has been laid very recently you may see only what looks like a tiny spot of blood.  Occasionally you will find this in a farm egg.  That is what will become the chick.  Depicted is a day 4 egg.
[image: day 4 chick embryo in egg]